# Fastest way to add a new blank stylesheet in Chrome's inspector developer tool ("Inspector stylesheet")

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Usually, when I want to test CSS modifications, live, in Chrome, I use:

- *Right click > Inspect*
- Use the bottom right pannel, and use the `+` button to add a new class, and then edit it there.

  [image]

But I've noticed there's even a handier way: open an "Inspector stylesheet" that opens a blank CSS document, that can be edited, and modifications are displayed live:

[image]

Question: **what's the easiest/fastest way to open such an "Inspector stylesheet" in Google Chrome?**

(by fastest, I mean faster than Right click, Inspect, `+` add a new class, click on the little inspector stylesheet link, etc.)

I cannot find it in a menu of Chrome's console/developer tools.
Is there a keyboard shortcut that would open such an "Inspector stylesheet"?

Comment: Only thing I can find is "F12" instead of "Right-click > Inspect"

Comment: Good idea. Then another thing: once an inspector stylesheet is created, if I close it or close the developer pannel, how to find it again ?

Comment: **(1)** If you close DevTools and the inspector-stylesheet is still open, just go to the *Sources* tab directly (in DevTools, topbar), the inspector-stylesheet should still be open. **(2)** If you've closed the inspector-stylesheet, then, while on the *Sources* tab, press `Ctrl+P` and type "inspector-stylesheet", usually after "in..." you will already see the inspector-stylesheet at the top of the dropdown-list of available files. And it should also still be visible at the top of the Styles-panel (bottom right) on the *Elements* tab, where you first created it.

Comment: Cool @myfunkyside, I think all your comments together make an answer to this question, feel free to post it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have one easy shortcut, but I can get you there a tiny bit faster:

1. <kbd>F12</kbd> to open DevTools.
2. [image] button at top of Styles-panel on *Elements* tab, to create inspector-stylesheet.
3. Doubleclick [image] to open.

---

*Once inspector-stylesheet is created, and I close it or close DevTools, how to find it again?*

- If you've closed DevTools when the inspector-stylesheet was still open, just go to the *Sources* tab directly (in DevTools, topbar) and the inspector-stylesheet should still be open.
- If you've closed the inspector-stylesheet itself, then, while on the *Sources* tab, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type *"inspector-stylesheet"*, usually after *"in..."* you will already see the inspector-stylesheet at the top of the suggestion-list of available files.
  And it should also still be visible at the top of the Styles-panel on the *Elements* tab, where you first created it.